# Importing ng2-bootstrap changes my tsc output directory structure

Tags: typescript, angular, tsc, ng2-bootstrap

I have the following folder structure

```
dist
src
  module1
    m1.ts
  module2
    m2.ts
.tsconfig.json
...
```

I have `tsc` configured to output to `dist/js` so after running `npm run tsc` I have the following:

```
dist
    js
      module1
          m1.js
      module2
          m2.js
src
...
```

After much struggle I have managed to integrate `ng-bootstrap` into my project.

If I `import` from `ng2-bootstrap` somewhere in my app, for example:

`import { ACCORDION_DIRECTIVES } from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/accordion';`

and run `npm run tsc` my folder structure changes to:

```
dist
    js
      node_modules
          ng2-bootstrap
             components
                accordian
                ...
      src
          module1
             m1.js
          module2
             m2.js
src
....
```

Why is this happening?

I am including: `<script src="/vendor/ng2-bootstrap/bundles/ng2-bootstrap.js"></script>` in my `index.html`

I am able to do this with angular2 
`<script src="/vendor/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script>`
and
`import {Component}  from 'angular2/core'` and this does not create a `dist/js/node_modules/angular2` folder

**Update**

Here is the contents of my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES5",
    "outDir": "./dist/js",
    "module": "system",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "typings/main",
    "typings/main.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Could you give us your `tsconfig.json`? Thanks!

Comment: Also might be worth mentioning, I had `"rootDir": "./src"` set in `tsconfig.json` that was fine until `"import .. from "ng2-bootstrap.."` then I would get the error `..node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/components/accordion.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'src'.` when running `npm run tsc`

Comment: refer this repo structure https://github.com/MrPardeep/Angular2-DatePicker looks same like this repo's structure

Comment: I have the same problem. Importing ng2-bootstrap creates in my dist folder node_modules as a sibling to src (which compiled content goes directly to dist if no ng2-bootstrap import is present). I offer a bounty, to get attention of typescript guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out a solution. Apparently the source `.ts` files are in the same directory as the `.d.ts`. and therefore it compiles these files. ( I read this somewhere along the way and I'm not sure the reasoning / why this happens ) however, the solution is to do remove all `.ts` igoring `*.d.ts` files in `node_modules/ng2-bootstrap`

I have created a `node script` to do this:

```
// ./scripts/hack-remove-files.js

var fs = require('fs-extra')
var glob = require("glob");

var options = { ignore: '**/*.d.ts'};

glob("node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/**/*.ts", options, function (er, files) {
    for(i in files){
        removeFile(files[i]);
    }
});

glob("node_modules/ng2-file-upload/**/*.ts", options, function (er, files) {
    for(i in files){
        removeFile(files[i]);
    }
});

removeFile = function(file){
    fs.remove(file, function (err) {
        if (err) return console.error(err)
    })
}
```

I run this as a `postinstall` script in npm:

```
"scripts": {
   ...
   "postinstall": "typings install && node ./scripts/hack-remove-files.js",
}
```

This only needs to be done 1 time, after downloading the package.

another command line approach would be:

`find node_modules/ng2-bootstrap -name '*.ts' | grep -v '\.d\.ts$' | xargs rm`

#### EDIT

I have found the original issue where this is all mentioned: https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-bootstrap/issues/128